# First navigation link is not working for the first time in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui

I have one navigationLink in the view but for the very first time its not clickable, but when i copy pasted same code below that the second navigationLink is working properly, I am not sure what is the issue with the first navigation (for the first time) only

```
if let groups = initialViewModel.groupsResponse {
// not clickable for first time 
    ABCBanner(bannerType: .info,
              bannerBody: "title",
               bannerCTA: "title",
       bannerCTACallback: { 
           initialViewModel.activateShow.toggle()
       })
    NavigationLink(destination: AlternatView(viewModel: AlternatViewModel(groups: Groups),
                                          showIsActive: $initialViewModel.activateShow),
                                              isActive: $initialViewModel.activateShow) { }

//clickable for first time 
    ABCBanner(bannerType: .info,
              bannerBody: "title",
               bannerCTA: "title",
       bannerCTACallback: { 
            initialViewModel.activateShow.toggle()
       })
    NavigationLink(destination: AlternatView(viewModel: AlternatViewModel(groups: Groups),
                                          showIsActive: $initialViewModel.activateShow),
                                              isActive: $initialViewModel.activateShow) { }
}
```